# Trigger Procedures

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to call a trigger when a column is updated in table X 
Trigger is inserting values from table X to table Y
can we just insert the values in X to Y using the column names in X?

Comment: i need the updated row/ columns data in table X to be inserted in the table y

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
create trigger tr_U_X 
on X
for Update
as
begin
    if update(email)
        insert into Y
            (name, email)
            select i.name, i.email
                from Inserted i
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. wat i needed value in a row from diff columns

Comment: lets say. i have name n email cloumns in table X and and a row with values having name Stan and email: xxxx@gmail.com..so if the email in this row got updated i want to insert into table Y the name n the updated email

Comment: @user512967: Edited my answer to match the details you've provided.

Comment: Thnks for the reply..couldnot understand how r the details from X going to Y?

Comment: @user512967: Every trigger has access to two special tables: `Inserted` and 'Deleted`. In an update, the `Deleted` table will contain the "before" version of the rows affected and the `Inserted` table will contain the "after" version of the rows affected. That is why I'm selecting the columns from the `Inserted` table in the trigger I wrote for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code to add trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trigger_Name BEFORE 

INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 

ON table_name REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

if condition > 0 then
         raise_application_error(-20010,'your message');
    end if;

END;
```

I have managed it my Financial ERP you can use it . Thank you .